# Is this a bug? Activator.CreateInstance with private access modifier constructor?

Tags: c#

So I had this Singleton code

```
public class Foo
{
    private static Foo instance;
    private Foo() { }
    public static Foo Instance
         {
             get
             {
                 if (instance == null) instance = Activator.CreateInstance<Foo>();
                    return instance;
             }
         }
}
```

Which didn't work because Foo's constructor is set to private (throws an exception that no parameterless constructor for that class is found).

Traditional `new Foo()` works there though (of course). I'm aware that Activator cannot access Foo's private constructor due to access restrictions, but I thought that every object instantiation was done by Activator: so why doesn't Activator work in that context?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably mean different override of [CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ca9yys8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your "instantiation was done by Activator"?

Comment: Why? new Foo() is much shorter.

Comment: @wonko79 academic question. Besides, there are lots of times where you are forced to do Activator.CreateInstance and I wanted to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Activator` is expecting only `public` constructors.  If you're interested in something other than `public`, then you need to call it differently:

```
(Foo)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Foo), nonPublic:true);
```

Unfortunately, the generic version doesn't really provide any additional options... Which means you get some **unboxing**.  However, you're also doing **reflection**, which is already slow... So I would guess this is more academic and less performance concerned.

Comment: Ohhh nonPublic: true nice catch. Generic version doesn't have that. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew, it wouldn't, generic version is casting internally.

Comment: @KonradKokosa You don't need to manually cast the new instance with the generic version of the CreateInstance method because it's already typed. I think he means that.

Comment: @KonradKokosa I'm more referring to losing the "elegance" of the generic version.  I think the cast is probably the fastest part of the entire operation when it comes to reflection.

Comment: @Andrew, If speaking in terms of "elegance", you are of course right. No one knows why there is no generic version with `nonPublic` flag. But your comment is misleading - sounds like generic version is not doing unboxing/casting.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a limitation of the `Activator` but only of the `CreateInstance` method version you have chosen. Change it to the version `CreateInstance(Type type, bool nonPublic)` and it will work:

```
if (instance == null) instance = (Foo)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Foo), true);
```

And remarks from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/he47tyc4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about this method:

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 1, this method can be used to access nonpublic types and members if the caller has been granted ReflectionPermission with the ReflectionPermissionFlag.RestrictedMemberAccess flag and if the grant set of the assembly that contains the nonpublic types and members is restricted to the caller’s grant set or to a subset thereof. (See Security Considerations for Reflection.)
>   To use this functionality, your application should target the .NET Framework 3.5 or later.